# Why does using myExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename) make the crash?

Tags: matlab

I run a VBA macro (Excel based) in Matlab. After 98 runs of a for loop (loop from 1 to 1000),  the program stops with an error.

I need to completely run the loop.
Thanks a lot.

Matlab code for running the Excel macro:

```
filename = 'G:\RUN\User.xlsm';
myExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
myExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
myExcel.Run('mySheet.myMacro', a);
```

Error:

> Error using Interface.000208DB_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/Open Invoke
>   Error, Dispatch Exception: Source: Microsoft Excel Description: Open
>   method of Workbooks class failed

Comment: Where is your loop? After the above code? Around it? If you are continually creating COM servers in a loop using [`actxserver`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html), make sure you close each in the loop as well with `Quit(myExcel); delete(myExcel);`.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve]